# Provide blame for tag wiki content

Tags: feature-request, tag-wiki

I can't do a "blame" for tag wikis. For example, in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/info , I can't see what edit added "which represents less than 28% of all browsers in use", and see if a vandal sneakily changed it from "2.8%" to "28%".

As there's [107 revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3607053/revisions) I can't see any other way of checking what edit was responsible for content (though an "expand all" option might help).

Comment: #94 in this case http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/3607053/94 http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5715225

Comment: I'm unsure what your feature request is here?

Comment: It's similar to how with `git blame` you can see which line by line was made by which edit/commit, with 10+ edit revisions, it's harder+ to sift through the revisions list

Comment: On another note, according to [StatCounter](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version_partially_combined-ww-monthly-201406-201506) IE8 currently is used by 2.91% of users and IE 6 and 7 are nowhere to be seen in the top 12. It would be safe to assume that it should be roughly 3% and not 28% (which is more than [IE's total usage for all versions put together](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser-ww-monthly-201406-201506)).

Answer (score 11):

If you are looking for a revision that is older than last sunday (that is when [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) gets its refresh) you could use the [following query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/339613/find-a-text-among-all-revisions-in-a-wiki-post?postid=3607053&searchfor=represents+less+than+2) ...

```sql
select creationdate
     , rev
     , userid as [User Link]
     , comment
     , text
from (
    -- first get all rows for a single post
    -- that reflect an edit
    -- to guarantee the revision nr is correct
    -- as it is dependant on the row_number
    select creationdate
         , row_number() over (order by creationdate asc) as rev
         , userid 
         , comment
         , text
    from posthistory
    where postid = ##postid:int?3607053## -- 3607053
    -- this works for wiki, for normal posts we need more magic
    -- because we have title and tag records as well
    and posthistorytypeid in (2, 5) -- initial body, edit body
) as main
where text like '%' + ##searchfor:String?represents less than 2##  + '%'
```

... to find the occurrences of the offending line of text.

You find the postid in the url of your browser when you click on the history link.

Do notice that the [text column of the PostHistory table](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/158100)  contains markdown so if the text you try find has markdown in it you need to use that in your search phrase as well.